# Relationship of Pump Power to Flow Rate

Tags: fluid-dynamics, power, flow

I read two different things about the relationship between power (P) of a pump and flow rate (Q). The most common thing that I found was simply that Q is directly proportional to P ([power-of-pump](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/63668/calculating-the-mechanical-power-of-a-water-pump/63671#63671)). But in [Wikipedia: Affinity Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affinity_laws), it states that Q is proportional to shaft speed (S), and P is proportional to the cube of shaft speed (S^3). This would indicate that Q is proportional to the P^(1/3).

Which is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power consumed by a pump is $P=\Delta p\times Q$, so if the pressure drop $\Delta p$ that the pump must provide is constant then the power $P$ would indeed be proportional to flow rate $Q$. In the Wiki article, impeller diameter is held constant (and not pressure drop) and in that case by dimensional arguments, $P~\alpha~ Q^3$.